# How can i set multiple CSS class from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, class

I have the following

**CSS:**

```
.a { position: absolute; }    
.a .b { color: red }    
.a .c { color: green }
```

How can i set the ".a .b" class for element with Java Script?

Comment: There is no **class** called `.a .b`. That CSS would only apply to elements with a class of `b` that are inside elements with a class of `a`.

Answer (score 5):

Via `className` property:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myelement');
element.className = 'a b';
```

However, as mentioned by [@dfsq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28628288/how-can-i-set-multiple-css-class-from-javascript/28628302#comment45556950_28628302) in the comments, you probably have to fix your CSS rules to set classes for the same element rather than for its descendants, e.g. `.a.b { color: red; }`.

**DOC:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.className

Comment: According to OP's CSS `a` and `b` are supposed to be on different elements. Probably CSS rules are not correct.

Comment: Like this? 
.в, .с { position: absolute }
.b { color: red }
.c { color: green }